# Navigation Item title issue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I've an `UITabBarController` connected with an UINavigationController related with an `UITableView` and finally connected with an `UIViewController`.
I've connected programmatically the `UITableView` with the `UIDetailViewController` using that code:

```
...
navigationController?.pushViewController(detail!, animated: true)
```

In my UIDetailViewController if I try to change the navigationItem.title like that:

```
self.navigationController!.navigationItem.title = "Hello"
```

Nothing happens. The navigation item doesn't change title.

Comment: Your code would work if your navigation controller (self.navigationController ) would be presented inside of another navigation controller with another navigation bar. Meaning that you are trying to update a title for the navigation controller, not your view controller.

Comment: I've tried to add anothe NavigationController. Same issue

Comment: Don't add another navigation controller, I don't think you want two navigations bar, do you ? What I'm saying is that you are updating the wrong navigation controller.

Comment: Can you post an answer? @A-Live

Comment: Have you solved the issue using this clues or is it still not clear ?

Comment: No, still not clear. Sorry

Comment: The project you linked previously has the right code `self.navigationItem.title = "Ciao"`, the issue there was that you were not using the `SecondViewController` class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101085/discussion-between-mala-and-a-live).

Answer (score 0):

You can change title of navigationItem title using this :-

self.navigationItem.title = "YourTitle";

**or other way is :-**

In UIDetailViewController write this line of code :

```
override func viewDidLoad()   
{            
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "ok"
}
```